# Wait for reducer to get data back before attempting to read it?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have the following code that will display data retrieved from an http call using Axios.

```
onCellClicked(event) {
    if (event.column.colId === 'fileId') {
        this.props.actions.getInterfaceFile(event.data.fileId);
        this.setState({ showModal: true })
        console.log(this.props.interfaceFile.fileBlob);
        this.setState({ fileDataBase64: decodedFile });

    }
}
```

Reducer code

```
switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_INTERFACE_FILE_LOADING_SUCCESS :
            return { ...state, interfaceFile: action.interfaceFile };
    default:
        return state;
}
```

Right now, the first time I click the cell the console shows the following error

"interfaceFile.jsx:136 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fileBlob' of undefined"

But if I click it the second time, the data is there. `actions.getInterfaceFile` makes an http call to get data back. How can the application wait until the data is back before I attempt to read it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `componentDidUpdate` to check when the API call success and `interfaceFile` updated.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if (this.props.interfaceFile !== prevProps.interfaceFile) {
    this.setState({ fileDataBase64: decodedFile });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I added componentDidUpdate as you suggested and it's working as expected. How would I check in the onCellClicked method that fileDataBase64 has been set using the componentDidUpdate?